# I'm stuck between 11.10 and 12.04 with only a read-only system

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, read-only, recovery-mode

I went out of the room while I was trying to update from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS. When I came back, my laptop had gone into sleep mode. I assume that it was half way through updating something. The screen would be black but would flash up with my background if I moved the mouse or pressed a key on the keyboard.

I restarted my computer and when I booted up the Ubuntu partition I was told,

> `GLIBC_2.14` is not found and is needed for `/lib/libply.so.2`

Then I was booted into some kind of recovery shell (I’ve forgotten exactly what it was called). From there, I tried to see whether the system could just pick up where the upgrade left off. I typed `do-release-upgrade -d` but simply got something like

> [Errno 30] Read Only file system when trying to access '/root/.cache/update-manager-core'

(Note: This is not the exact wording.)

From there, I went onto the Windows partition (where everything seems as normal). Then I went back to Ubuntu in recovery mode and tried to recover packages with dpkg. It ran and said that to fix some problems I would need to manually run `dpkg --configure -a`. I went to the recovery shell and tried this, and was told that I couldn’t do it because of a ‘Read-only file system’.

I’m running a HP Pavilion dv6 which started with Windows 7. I added Ubuntu on after a while. Note that `sudo` doesn’t do anything in the recovery shell.

What should I do to get out of this situation and complete the upgrade?

Comment: I think this is not a problem with your laptop going into sleep mode, I think this is surely a bug with the 12.04 cannonical update. I am facing the same problem I was running 11.10 and upgraded to 12.04LTS and was sitting right in front of my laptop till the installation finished. After rebooting its giving a message that MY file system is read-only  and it is not finding GLIBC_2.14 and even dpkg --configure -a saying read-only file system.

Answer (score 4):

boot into the recovery shell again and `mount -o remount,rw /` that will remount the filesystem read/write.
Then you can try to repair your system.

Comment: didnt worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to respond using the account I used to ask the question but I used the command that ruediger suggested and it worked fine. If anyone is interested I then used `apt-get install -g` and this sorted everything out. There my be a little bug with updating but nothing that breaks my computer, Thanks.